# document.images not loaded on chrome or firefox, but it is loaded on IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

I have an anchor tag `<a>` with an image tag `<img>` within it, and I call javascript functions on that anchor tag as follows:

```
<a href="javascript: foo();"><img ...></a>
<a href="javascript: foo();"><img ...></a>
<a href="javascript: foo();"><img ...></a>
```

Inside `foo()` function, I used [`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.images) to retrieve an array that contains the 3 images. It works well in IE, but it doesn't work on chrome and firefox!

`document.images.length` returns 3 on IE, and returns 0 on Chrome and Firefox. Do you have any suggestions to solve this issue?!

Comment: what happens if you print the length of document.images outside the function? I tried it on FF and it actually works.

Comment: @Smokie If I invoke `document.images.length` just after the last anchor tag , it will print 3 on all browsers.

Comment: Can we see the full foo() function?

Comment: Can you give us a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I bet there should be something wrong in the foo() function, would be very helpful if you could paste it here...

Comment: See if this returns the right amount: http://jsfiddle.net/d2ngY/1/ it works for me in chrome and ff

Comment: @SoonDead That works for me in chrome! I very much agree with Smokie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<img>` tags are in a different document in a frame.

First resolve the right frame object in the main document. If you have a name for the frame, then do something like the following:

```
var frame = document.querySelector("frame[name='NAME']");
```

If you don't name your frames, then you will have to index the frame on the array of frames returned by `document.getElementsByTagName('frame');`

To access all the images in the document you can do:

```
frame.contentDocument.images
```

or

```
frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

Comment: +1 You are right. I solved it by just replacing `document` with `parent.frames[2].document` :)

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't [`document.getElementsByTagName('img')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) work for you?

It doesn't return an array, but a node list. If you need an array:

```
 var imgNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
 var images = [].slice.call(imgNodes);
```

Comment: Exactly the same result. Thanks for your response anyway :)

Comment: I daresay `document.querySelectorAll('img')` returns an empty list, too, does it?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Are those img tags inside an iframe/frameset?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  That's the reason all the API's will not work. Your img tags are in a different document. First resolve the right document and then make the getElementsByTagName or images property access.

Answer (score -1):

Or use jQuery.

```
$('img').each(function(){
        // do something with $(this).
});
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted and Kay's answer upvoted? This alternative is just as reasonable as Kay's.

Comment: Seems it got lifted. And I forgot! +1!